# Can't edit file after `chattr +i`

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, hosts

After

```
chattr +i /etc/hosts
```

I can't edit this file (obviously). But how can I revert it back. I need to edit this file and then lock again.

**UPD**

```
ls -l /etc/hosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 274 2011-06-09 14:14 /etc/hosts
```

**UPD 2**

```
lsattr /etc/hosts
-----a-----------e- /etc/hosts
```

**UPD 3**

Thanx, @womble, I've removed `a` attribute

```
chattr -a /etc/hosts
```

Comment: `lsattr /etc/hosts` would be useful to see.  Also, "Operation is denied" is not the usual error message you'd expect to see for a permissions problem; I suspect something else is wrong.

Comment: @womble `Operation is denied` is my translation of error from my localization.

Comment: Please don't do your own translations; get error messages in the `C` locale and post them directly -- exact wording can be critical in diagnosing what's gone wrong.

Comment: @womble, Thank you! I don't know how can I switch locale for only one command (it is system-wide). I can switch to `English` in whole system only.

Comment: `LANG=C <command>` will do it.

Comment: `Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chattr -i` will remove immutability, then you can `chattr +i` it again afterwards.

**EDIT**

Based on your `lsattr` output, you've also set "append-only".  Clear that as well (`chattr -a`).

Comment: and what if not? It is still `denied` to edit. I've tried it already before I wrote my question. Looks like something is messed in permissions to this file.

Comment: Did you edit it as root? Or, as in the world of Ubuntu, `sudo <yourtexteditor> /etc/hosts`?

Comment: @Janne Pikkarainen yep of course :). But it still throws an error `Operation is denied`.

Comment: Add more info to your question, not comments.  Also, if you've already tried that, why didn't you mention it in your question?

Comment: @womble, done :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have (accidentally|purposely) made your `/etc` immutable as well. Try `chattr -i /etc` as well. If that was not the case, please fill your question more. Give us `stat /etc` and `stat /etc/hosts` as well as `lsattr /etc/hosts`.

Can you modify any other file under `/etc`?

**EDIT after your own edit**: You have `a` attribute set for `/etc/hosts`. That means you can only append to that file, every other write operation is denied. Try `chattr -a /etc/hosts`.

Comment: QUestion is updated. I can edit other files

Comment: And my answer is edited, too.

Comment: fl00r: Don't be shy, we can all guess how it happened. Enough administrative beer and a willingness to harden your server can lead to interesting situations.

Answer (score 1):

The `a` attribute makes your file append-only, use `chattr -a` to remove it. See `man 1 chattr` to see what all other attribute flags are are.